# Getting debug error "No cells were found"

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I am trying to change some existing code to accommodate inserting two rows. The code looks sound but it keeps giving me the debug error *No cells found*. The code had a `1` in for the Offset value, which worked fine. Once I added the two rows, I changed the Offset value to `3`, but then it started to give me a debug error. Before the two row addition:

```
    With Sheets("Main")
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="SC Link"
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).SpecialCells _
            (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
    End With
```

After the two row addition:

```
    With Sheets("Main")
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="SC Link"
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(3).SpecialCells _
            (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
    End With
```

Does anyone see anything I don't?

Comment: Screenshot of how your data looks on the sheet would help

Comment: Can you also post the code that has the addition of the two rows?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your problem, but you need to be careful when using `SpecialCells` in cases where the area you're using it on might be outside of the sheet's `UsedRange` (which doesn't always get reset when you might expect)

Eg:

Starting with an empty sheet, add some data in the first row only (say A1:F1)

Then run this

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

...gives a run-time error because the second row is not within the current UsedRange.

If you enter a value in (e.g.) J10 and then re-run the code above it will no longer give an error.
If you delete the value from J10 the code continues to run without error because `UsedRange` doesn't get reset automatically.  If you run

```
? ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address()
```

in the Immediate pane then that will reset UsedRange and the SpecialCells will again cause a runtime error.